# Can we create a Monorepo with Python and Vue projects?

Tags: python, vue.js, monorepo

I am trying to set up a monorepo with rush where I intend to put a python backend and Vue frontend. But I am getting this error when I run rush update command.

Can any help me with setting up this monorepo.
Currently this is the project struture!

[project structure for the backend and frontend with rush](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krb8u.png)

I used Rush to set up a monorepo with python project but getting error that package.json doesnot exists

Comment: are you using pnpm? One possible solution is to switch to using the "npm".

Comment: Make sure you have package.json in you root directory. This file contains all your dependencies needed for vue.js app After that also check the official Rush [docs](https://rushjs.io/pages/intro/get_started/).

Comment: Sure you can create a monorepo, but why?!

Comment: Just trying new stuffs! Could you tell me how to combine python and js repos together